# Which form is it of Mahavishnu mentioned here?

Tags: vishnu

As per wikipedia article on [Vaikhanasas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaikhanasas):

> Vaikhanasas claim to be a surviving school of Vedic ritual, the Taittiriya Shakha of the Krishna Yajurveda. Vaikhanasa tradition says the sage Vikhanasa, who was a manifestation of Lord Mahavishnu, had the Upanayanam along with Brahma consecrated by His father Lord Mahavishnu and educated under Lord Mahavishnu all the Vedas and Bhagawat Saastra on how to worship SriBhagawaan in **His Archaavathaara - Iconic Form**.

My question is which form is it? Is there any detailed description of this form mentioned in scripture?

Comment: @Archit Can it be any idol or it has some specific appearance?

Answer (score 1):

*Archavatara* is one of the forms of God. It is the idol form of God.

> Again, when certain images are made of earth, stone, or metals, and they are properly installed with proper ceremonials, these are inspired with the presence of God and with His special powers. These are called arcāvatāras, or image-incarnations, for purposes of worship by which all desirable ends may be achieved.

> There are thus five kinds of existence for the Lord:

> firstly as his absolute state (para),
> secondly as vyūha,
> thirdly as vibhavāvatāra (primary and secondary),
> fourthly as antaryāmin,
> and fifthly as arcāvatāra

> [Source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-3/d/doc209941.html)